# Ubuntu 18.04 : how to set MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD = yes

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel

i'm newbie. i'm build a driver devices.
how to remove kernel modules. i try rmmod -r 'name-modules':
console prints
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'hello_kernel_modules': Function not
implemented
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module hello_kernel_modules: Function not implemented

how to set MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD = yes in ubuntu 18.04 ?

Comment: You would have to compile the kernel with `CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD=y` in your kernel configuration file. don't you just do `sudo rmmod module-name`? But if your module hasn't implement a `module_exit`, or whatever the proper term is, that is what should be done.

Comment: my file .c:
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Sachith Muhandiram");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple first Linux module");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0.0");
static int __init initHelloWorld(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, this is my first kernel module \n");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit exitHelloWorld(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Exit Hello world module\n");
}
module_init(initHelloWorld);
module_exit(exitHelloWorld);"

Comment: when i do: "sudo rmmod hello_kernel_modules". my console prints: "Module hello_kernel_modules is in use" and i add parameter -f : sudo rmmod -f hello_kernel_modules . my console prints: rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module() could 
not remove 'hello_kernel_modules': Function not implemented
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module hello_kernel_modules: Function not impleme
nted

Answer (score 0):

Currently, CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD is still not well implemented in the Linux kernel. Even after you set CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD=yes, `rmmod -f nvidia` will stuck until you manually close all applications using that driver, e.g., Firefox uses nvidia driver for hardware video decoding. So CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD is quite useless for now.